# Get Param from react-router 6 in react class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm using ReactJs version 18.2 and react-router-dom version 6.21.1.

In my application I added a route like this:
*<Route path="/modify/:id" element={} />*

and in my "Modify" component I want to retrieve the value of "id" param.

My "Modify" react component is written as Class component using typescript (tsx file).
For example:

```
class Modify extends Component {
 ....
}
```

I cannot find a way to retrieve the param!

I tried "**useParams**" hook but in class component it doesn't work returning error related to react hooks rule violation.

I tried also to import these:

*import { **RouteComponentProps, withRouter** } from 'react-router-dom';*

but it cannot find "RouteComponentProps" and "withRouter".

So, I don't know how to do it and that's crazy.
Can anyone help me? (maybe providing a working example)

Comment: Hey! Check the first example at https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq

Comment: Hi @Sylent, I already checked that page but they added examples not related to Class component… those samples are not working in class components 

Comment: The `withRouter` HOC was removed in RRDv6. Also, there are no longer any route props, so they were removed as well. Everything uses the React hooks now. Either convert to React function components so you can use the hooks or follow the instructions in the duplicate to create a custom `withRouter` HOC to inject props for your React class components.

Comment: I found a solution! I created a new component called "withRouter.tsx" with the typescript implementation of "WithRouterProps" and "withRouter" that inside use the react hooks.
After that you can import these into your class component and follow the old way and it works!